# Iteration new object instance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I'm new to OOP Python I have an object:

```py
class Object:

    def __init__(self, start_date, end_date, thing)
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date 
        self.thing = thing

       ( ... ) 


    def get_things(self):
        return self.db.execute_fetchall(f"select date, p1, p2, p2, p4 from {self.thing} where date between '{self.start_date}' and '{self.end_date}'")

       ( ... )
```

Now if I have:

```
some_things = ["table_1", "table_2", "table_3"]
```

```
Object.get_things()
```

The method just selects a given table, but I want to try to be as efficient as possible. Is there any other way to poll the DB for all 3 table names other than:

```
for thing in things: 
    Object(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, thing=thing)
```

Should I just have this sort of logic in a bulk statement and have a `get_all()` method? 
The tables (static) I select will always be the same and I'm looking for the fastest way to select data from them...

Comment: i think you are looking for `select t1.A, t2.B from tableA as t1, tableB as t2` (im not entirely sure i dont write much raw sql these days)

Comment: So are you suggesting just having it in a raw sql command instead

Comment: The bulk of execution time is in the sql statement, not the python code. On the python side, you are interested in how you want to express the data layer. If the tables are always the same but the dates can change, then the tables should be hard coded in the class. Why should the caller even have to know what they are? When these change on the next big DB restructuring, you don't have to chase down all the callers of the class.

Comment: @Alex you are doing raw sql already there ... on the execute fetchall ... you just need to adjust that query ...

Comment: @alex, for this simple case a single function is a good solution. The class made things more complex and there may be no benefit.

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes you are right

Comment: @tdelaney Okay cool, see there is a lot more to the class then just this method, but the method needs to be extended to poll for 1 table or 10 table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a class variable so that you don't have to aggregate your collection of things.

```
class object:
    things = []
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
        self.things.append(thing)
    def get_things(self):
        return(self.things)

a = object(1)
b = object(2)
c = object(3)

print(a.get_things()) # Prints [1, 2, 3]
```

This will likely be the fastest way as your list of things will be stored in memory and retrieving the aggregated list will not require any computation. It should be noted that this approach has its own drawbacks. For example if you change the value of some object.thing you will need to reflect that change in the list object.things as well and you will see some additional work is required for things like deletion or overriding of object instances.

Comment: I like this approach will give it a go, may extend it to have pandas dfs

Comment: As an additional note your code might be cleaner if you reference `object.things` as opposed to `a.things`. It's effectively the same just a readability thing.

Comment: Yes agreed and when you are instantiating the object, I would still do 
`for thing in things: object(thing)` right?

Comment: yeah I guess... It's kinda hard to say without more context.

Comment: I think this approach is likely to be problematic since the list of objects isn't being properly maintained. For example, if you do a `del b`, after the `print()` shown, then do `print(a.get_things())` again, it will still display all three objects even though `b` should no longer exist.

Comment: for my use case, this will not be an issue. I will take the list out into some config, but it will never change. I extended this and used: `self.cost_components.extend(map(some_things, lambda thing: object()))`